# struts 2 - Passing parameters from one page to another

Tags: java, struts2

Help needed passing parameters with Struts 2.

```
<action name="Hfddisp1" class="model.HfddispAction" method="fetch_addesc">
   <result  >model.HfddispAction?ad_ref_no=${ad_ref_no}</result> 
</action>
```

My jsp is

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
<body>
   <h1> Iterator tag example 12</h1>
   <h3>Iterator with IteratorStatus 12</h3>
   <table>
      <tr class="even"> 
         <td><b>Ad_ref_no</b></td> 
         <td><b>Ad_title</b></td> 
      </tr> 
      <s:iterator value="hftbList" status="hftbListStatus">
      <tr>
  <s:if test="#hftbListStatus.even == true">
         <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property value="ad_ref_no"  /> </td>
         <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property value="ad_title" />  </td>
         <td  style="background: #CCCCCC">     
            <a href="<s:url action="Hfddisp1"/>">click here-1 </a>   
         </td>  
      </s:if>       
      <s:else>
         <td>
            <s:property value="ad_ref_no" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <s:property value="ad_title" />
         </td>
         <td >
            <a href="<s:url  action="Hfddisp2"/>
               <s:param name="ad_ref_no" value="%    {ad_ref_no}" />  ">
               click       here2
            </a>   
         </td>
      </s:else>
   </tr>
   </s:iterator>
   </table>
```

Error i am getting is:

Messages: No result defined for action model.HfddispAction and result huge volume of test goes here i can say what is it

File: file:/E:/Web_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Gshax/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml

I am getting the data in the iterator but can not show it in another page.

```
<--------qry is executed2hftb_add_master[ad_ref_no=huge volume of test goes here i can say what is it,email_address=null]
<--------qry is executed2huge volume of test goes here i can say what is it 
description successfully queried:1 huge volume of test goes here i can say what is it
Apr 26, 2012 12:07:04 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher serviceAction
SEVERE: Could not find action or result
```

From the first page the output i get is

```
Ad_ref_no Ad_title 

12123120  i am the king but not sing  click here-1  
213421123  new test1  click here-2  
4150  Ad_title ........11:32:08  click here-1  
4152  Ad_title ........11:32:09  click here-2  
4153  Ad_title ........11:32:10  click here-1
```

when I click the click here -1 i am getting the above error 
ALL  I AM TRYING IS TO PASS THE THE AD REF NO 4150 TO THE ACTION AND DISPLAY DESCRIPTION IN ANOTHER PAGE

Comment: wht URL you are able to see by this expression `<a href="<s:url  action="Hfddisp2"/>  <s:param name="ad_ref_no" value="%    {ad_ref_no}" />  ">`?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Struts2 url and param tags...

Currently you have this: `<s:url  action="Hfddisp2"/><s:param name="ad_ref_no" value="%    {ad_ref_no}" />` Note that the param tag is not nested inside the url tag.

You could write this: `<s:url action="Hfddisp2"><s:param name="ad_ref_no"/></s:url>`

Note in the above that the param tags value attribute is omitted because it defaults to resolving the name provided.

With several attributes using a variable can make things clearer:

```
<s:url var="myurl" action="Hfddisp2">
   <s:param name="ad_ref_no"/>
</s:url>
```

Then later where ever you need it:

```
<s:property value="#myurl"/>
```

Also you should be able to include all the parameters in the current url into the new url by saying:

```
<s:url action="Hfddisp2" includeParams="get"/>
```

For more information always consult the tag reference http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/tag-reference.html